# Can't make C++ compiler throw an error using type traits conditionally

Tags: c++, templates, embedded, template-specialization, type-traits

I am trying to learn/evaluate C++ for embedded programming and have run into a problem, which I don't seem to be able to solve on my own. I would like to use type traits to describe the different possible uses of a specific microcontroller pin. Then I would like to make the compiler stop compiling my project, if a pin is used for something it cannot actually do. My problem is that it either works only at runtime, or the compiler produces *false positives*: i.e. it insists a pin cannot be used for some function, even when I never attempt to use it as such, but only as something else (like drive a LED)...

Please excuse the lengthy post - I hope you can bear with my explanation and help me find a solution.

I have created an implementation for the MCU pins using templates, like this:

```cpp
enum class pin_funciton {
    OUTPUT, INPUT, INTERRUPT_FALLING,
    INTERRUPT_RISING, INTERRUPT_LEVEL,
    ANALOG, SPI, UART, };

// base class is needed so instance can be passed as function arguments
class gpio {
public:
    virtual void configure(pin_function, unsigned char startupLogic) = 0;
    virtual void set() {}
    virtual void reset() {}
    /* ... other functions like read() etc. */
};

template<unsigned int GPIO_BASE, unsigned int pin>
class gpio_pin : public gpio {
public:
    void configure(pin_function, unsigned char startupLogic = 0U) override {
        /* actual implementation based on options */
    }
    // other methods are implemented as well
};

void do_stuff(gpio* signalPin) {
    // do some very super duper useful work
}

// other usage
gpio_pin<GPIOB, 4> redLed;
redLed.set();
```

This all works so far fairly well. Enter type traits. When the pin is being configured for use, type traits should inform the compiler if the pin can be used as such or not. Here is one possible trait implementation example:

```cpp
template<unsigned int port, unsigned int pin>
struct is_spi_pin {
    static constexpr bool allow() {
        switch (port) {
            case GPIOE_BASE: if (pin == 1 || pin == 2) return true; break;
            case GPIOC_BASE: if (pin == 1 || pin == 2 || pin == 3) return true; break;
            case GPIOB_BASE: if (pin == 10 || pin == 12 || pin == 14) return true; break;
            default: return false;
         }
     }
};
```

This was the first complication I came across. I am aware that the typical convention is to achieve this through template specialization, i.e. the preferred way is something like:

```cpp
template<unsigned int port, unsigned int pin>
struct is_spi_pin {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<>
struct is_spi_pin<GPIOE_BASE, 1> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<>
struct is_spi_pin<GPIOE_BASE, 2> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
/* rest of the SPI pins specializations ... */
```

However, I did not want to implement a specialization for all possible usage types of all pins of the MCU, so I thought I could do with a constexpr function. I could have one function per usage type and it would save me some time and work. Please advise, if my solution is undesirable and for what reason...

Then, here is the use case that's giving me fits...

I have another, similar template class for the SPI peripheral:

```cpp
enum class spi_type {
    SPI_TYPE0, SPI_TYPE1, SPI_TYPE2, SPI_TYPE4
};

class spi {
public:
    virtual void configure(unsigned int speed, spi_type spiType) = 0;
    virtual unsigned char write(unsigned char dat) = 0;
    virtual void write(unsigned char* buffer, size_t bufferSz) = 0;
    virtual void read(unsigned char* dest, size_t  destSz) = 0;
};

template<unsigned int SPI_BASE>
class spi_periph : public spi {
public:
    spi_periph(gpio* clkPin, gpio* mosiPin, gpio* misoPin)
        : clk_(clkPin), mosi_(mosiPin), miso_(misoPin) { }
    void configure(unsigned int speed = 2000000LU,
                   spi_type spiType = spi_type::SPI_TYPE0) override {
        /* ... */
    }
    // other functions ...
private:
    gpio *clk_{ nullptr }, *mosi_{ nullptr }, *miso_{ nullptr };
};

// usage
gpio_pin<GPIOA, 5> errorLed{};
errorLed.configure(pin_function::OUTPUT);

gpio_pin<GPIOC, 0> clk{};
gpio_pin<GPIOC, 3> mosi{};
spi_periph<SPI0> spi0{ &clk, &mosi, nullptr };
spi0.configure(/*...*/);
```

In the `spi::configure` function, the implementation calls `gpio::confugure` wiht pin_function::SPI on all pins (if not nullptr). I want the compiler to throw an error, if the gpio type traits say that either the clock, mosi or miso pins cannot be SPI pins.

Here is my implementation of the `gpio::configure` function:

```cpp
template<unsigned int port, unsigned int pin>
void gpio_pin<port, pin>::configure(pin_function useAs, unsigned char initialLogic) {
    switch (useAs) {
        case pin_function::SPI:
            assert(is_spi_pin<port, pin>::allow());
            // configure as SPI pin
            break;
        case pin_function::OUTPUT:
            // configure as output
            break;
        /* other cases */
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this works only at runtime. If I replace the assert with static_assert, then the compiler will not flag the clk and mosi instantiations as errors, if the type traits say they are SPI pins. But *it flags the* `errorLed.configure` *call as error, if GPIOA pin 5 is not an SPI pin, even though I am not trying to use it for that*!

Is this solvable??? And if yes, then how?

Thanks for reading all of this, and of course, for all the help you can provide!

Comment: I think the crux of the problem is `void do_stuff(gpio* signalPin)`. What magic function do you have that works on _all_ pins? I would hide that away as an implementation detail, and not have a `gpio` class.

Comment: If you absolutely must have a base class, then the problem is `spi_periph(gpio* clkPin, gpio* mosiPin, gpio* misoPin)`.  If `clkPin` must be a `SPI` pin, then make it only accept `SPI` pins, not all `gpio` pins.

Comment: But without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to understand the problems you're facing, and thus hard to come up with solutions

Comment: @MooingDuck, thank you for your comments. There is not much difference between `void do_stuff(gpio* signalPin)` and `template<unsigned int SPI_BASE> spi_periph<SPI_BASE>::spi_periph(gpio* clk, gpio* mosi, gpio* miso)`. Since `template<unsigned port, unsigned pin> class gpio_pin` is not a type on its own until instantiated, I cannot use is as a paramter to the spi class constructor. I have to use the base class for that, as far as I understand things...

Comment: `template<unsigned int SPI_BASE> template<unsigned port, unsigned pin> spi_periph<SPI_BASE>::spi_periph(gpio_pin<port, pin>* clk, gpio* mosi, gpio* miso)` works just fine.

Comment: @MooingDuck, the suggestion by @max66 below works just fine. I just tested out changing the code to `template<unsigned port, unsigned pin, pin_function usage> class gpio_pin { /*... */ };`. But this takes away the ability to reconfigure the pin function during runtime (granted, only relevant when an output or input pin needs to become high impedance or vs versa, but still...)

Comment: @MooingDuck, however, if your last suggestion works, then I can get rid of the base class and make the configure function a template function itself since it doesn't need to be virtual anymore: something like `template<unsigned port, unsigned pin> class gpio { public: template<pin_function usage> void confugure(); /* other function */ };` Let me give it a try

Comment: Not that you're wrong, but to make sure: Are you aware that neither of those are what I suggested?  My suggestion was for `template<unsigned int SPI_BASE> class spi_periph` to have a constructor that was `template<unsigned port, unsigned pin> spi_periph(gpio_pin<port, pin>* clk, gpio* mosi, gpio* miso)`. The constructor is specific to the specific pin type, but the class and it's members aren't.

Comment: @MooingDuck, what you suggest won't work at all, the spi_periph constructor needs 3 unique gpio* arguments, which in turn point to 3 distinct instantiations of gpio_pin<port, pin> template. Having only the clk parameter as template doesn't solve anything

Comment: `template<unsigned port1, unsigned pin1, unsigned port2, unsigned pin2, unsigned port3, unsigned pin3> spi_periph(gpio_pin<port1, pin1>* clk, gpio_pin<port2, pin2>* mosi, gpio_pin<port3, pin3>* miso)` So add more template parameters

Comment: I've seen so many broken, bloated wrappers and HALs around really simple GPIO or register access... please, just don't do it - these are simple things, very easy to use as-is. No abstraction layer needed. The problem here isn't even C++ (though it is always happy to provide the means for blowing your whole leg off), it's inventing a solution without a problem that it solves. Write the abstraction layer around the _whole peripheral_ instead, not around individual pins or registers.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, this works only at runtime. If I replace the assert with static_assert, then the compiler will not flag the clk and mosi instantiations as errors, if the type traits say they are SPI pins.

Sure.

If you can use C++17, and you can pass `useAs` as template parameter, you can solve the problem whit a chain of `if constexpr`.

So, instead of

```
switch (useAs) {
    case pin_function::SPI:
        assert(is_spi_pin<port, pin>::allow()); // <-- compilation error if static_assert
        // configure as SPI pin
        break;
    case pin_function::OUTPUT:
        // configure as output
        break;
    /* other cases */
}
```

you can write

```
if constexpr ( pin_function::SPI == useAs )
 {
   static_assert(is_spi_pin<port, pin>::allow());
   // configure as SPI pin
 }
else if constexpr ( pin_function::OUTPUT == useAs )
 {
   // configure as output
 }
```

Observe that you have to pass `useAs` as template parameter or the compiler can't compile the `is constexpr`s.

The problem is that if you use `switch/case` (or a chain if simple `if`) the compiler has to compiler everything, also when not used. So your `alert()` works because is checked only run-time (and only when `useAs` is `pin_function::SPI`) but your `static_assert()` give a compilation error because is checked compile time also when `useAs` is different from `pin_function::SPI`

`if constexpr` exist exactly to avoid this sort of problem and cut the unused code in the compilation phase.

Without C++17... you have to develop different methods for different cases (or accept an `assert()` working run-time).

Comment: your solution works, but... For the usage to be a template parameter, it either has to be part of the class template parameters, or the configure function has to be a template function. Since the configure functions is virtual, it cannot be a template function (any way around that?). In the other case, it works, but has an unfortunate side effect. Since it is now part of the instance type, it prevents me to  `configure` the same instance more than once and change how the pin is used. That would be useful when an input or output pin needs to become high impedance.